# Cakephp how to redirect back to http protocol from https

Tags: php, cakephp, mod-rewrite, ssl

I understand how to force SSL on certain pages but how do I redirect other pages without https connection?

The reason is that I have external javascript and images running on other pages and they do not need to be secure but it gets redirected from my secure payment page with https and it creates padlock with red cross on it.

Thanks

Comment: you cannot usage http stuff while in https. you are destroying the whole purpose of https and therefore the red cross is a legit warning for all users of your site. you need to serve ALL content (even the smallest image) via https if you force ssl.

Comment: Sorry Mark I already know that and that was not my question. The question is how can we force http protocol on other pages within Cakephp environment

Comment: Couldnt you remove the forceSsl logic and redirect to http. If you want to force, check in beforeFilter for the controller/actions you want http since there is no built-in forceHttp method like forceSsl afaik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cake Book has an [example how to force SSL](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html):

```
public function forceSSL() {
    $this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->here);
}
```

The `forceSSL()` function is used in a callback of the SecurityComponent that is called if a page is accessed without https.

There is no such callback the other way round, but `SecurityComponent::requireSecure` is an array of all actions that are https-only, if set up using the `requireSecure()` function.

So you can do something like this in your AppController:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    // Check if current action is secure but shouldn't be
    if( 
        $this->request->is('ssl')
        &&
        !in_array($this->request->params['action'], $this->Security->requireSecure) 
    ){
        // Redirect to the http URL
        $this->redirect('http://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->here);
    }
}
```